# Slight change of query causes CONVERT of illegal values to be done first, causing a conversion error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization, statistics, type-conversion

I have a table `MyTable` which has columns `OldVal`, `NewVal`, `Nme` which are all `VARCHAR(MAX)`

Wherever `Nme` = `MyValue`, the `OldVal` and `NewVal` values will be "integers" IE a numeric value value stored as a `VARCHAR`

Wherever `Nme` = `SomethingElse`, the `OldVal` and `NewVal` values will be "bigints"

Wherever `Nme` = `SomethingElseAgain`, the `OldVal` and `NewVal` values are string values

If I run the following query

```
SELECT   OldVal,
         NewVal
FROM     MyTable
WHERE    Nme = 'MyValue' AND
         CONVERT(INT,NewVal) < CONVERT(INT,OldVal)
```

The query runs as expected.

However If I change the query to

```
SELECT  1
FROM    (
            SELECT  OldVal,
                    NewVal
            FROM    MyTable
            WHERE   Nme = 'MyValue' AND
                    CONVERT(INT,NewVal) < CONVERT(INT,OldVal)
        ) a
```

I get an error

> The conversion of the varchar value '3666999000' overflowed an int
>   column.

The value in question in the error message is one where `Nme = "SomethingElse"` (which are all `BIGINT`s stored as `VARCHAR`s)

it seems to me that what is happening here is that on the first query, the optimizer first filters by `Nme = 'MyValue'` and then does the conversions on the residual data and the second query tries to do the conversion first (meaning it tries to convert values that are illegals `INT`s) and then applies the `Nme = 'MyValue'` filter.

This is confirmed by the predicate in the tooltip on the filter operator in each (Estimated) execution plan

The database is on a 2014 server and running in Compatibility Level 110. The behaviour is still present if I force the 2014 optimizer with `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 2312)`

What would cause this to happen? I suspect maybe something to do with wrapping `NewVal` and `OldVal` in a `CONVERT` is causing issues with statistics but surely that would have affected both queries?

NB - above is abridged code narrowed down to its simplest form for the purpose of demostrating it here
also, I know storing ints as varchars is not good practice but this is a third party database which we cannot control the design of

Comment: You could move WHERE clause outside the subquery. `IF EXISTS(SELECT  1
          FROM    (
                   SELECT  OldVal,
                           NewVal
                   FROM    MyTable
                   WHERE   Nme = 'MyValue'
                  ) a
          WHERE CONVERT(INT,NewVal) < CONVERT(INT,OldVal))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'IT EXISTS'
END`